# What are the main differences between PEP8 and Google Python Style Guide?

Tags: python, pep8, google-style-guide

1. most notably they use two spaces for indentation instead of 4.
2. The CamelCase style for functions and methods instead of the camel_case style.

Comment: This may have been the case at the time of posting. But it's probably worth noting that in today's Google Style guide the recommendation is 4 spaces. And it doesn't look like CamelCasing is a thing with the functions anymore


See indentation here: https://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html#34-indentation

See functions here: https://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html#383-functions-and-methods

Answer (score 7):

the main difference is that Google Python Style comes with more details about how to write code, for example how to write your docstrings or when to use aliases for a variable, this are not specified in the [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)